# Enable null safety in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

## **Enable null safety in flutter?**

Please help me to fix this error.

[image]

I tried flutter upgrade cmd but it didn't fix the problem.

When I click get dependencies, I get an error like the screenshot

Can you tell me the best solution for this

Answer (score 2):

Change in your pubspec.yaml

`sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0`

to
`sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0`

Comment: then i got this error           C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.2.

Because mi_card depends on cupertino_icons >=0.1.1 <1.0.1 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '<2.0.0 or >=2.0.0-dev.28.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Can you show me the complete pubspec.yaml?

Comment: sure  https://ibb.co/kSYdrtG

Comment: Upate also your cupertino_icons to `^1.0.5`. You can always find the latest version at https://pub.dev/

Comment: done, I tried to copy new project yaml codes to error yaml file then it works, thank you very much brother 